# Handle Javascript focus when using sendKeys in WebDriver

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver, onload

It's quite common for a web application to use Javascript to focus to a text field onload. For example, in a login page, we may use Javascript to focus to the username field.

When using WebDriver with FirefoxDriver, I use sendKeys to populate these fields. However, most of the time, the Javascript focus function will get executed **while** WebDriver is sending actual characters, so my input for another field (e.g. the password field) is partial and the remaining goes to the focused field.

How should I handle this case? To my knowledge, the blocking API returns when the page content is loaded, not when Javascript execution is finished, so this situation is understandable. However, I don't think using "Wait" is a decent solution, since it means too much intrusion to the test development.

Comment: Not an actual answer, but you could try setting the value of the field "directly" by javascript as a sort of workaround. In Java, that would be:
`((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('someId').value = 'some value'");`

Comment: Interesting idea, Slanec. However, then it's not the purpose of using WebDriver anymore ;)

Comment: Unforntunately, you're right. My best guess to solve this is to wait for `driver.switchTo().activeElement()` to return the onload focused element. Simply put, you have to make webdriver slow as a human :).

Comment: Hi Slanec, I want to do assertion whether a focus is present or not on a text field. How can I do that?

Comment: @Slanec: It's nice and interesting idea to input text value by using Javascript. For entering google search text: jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('gbqfq').value = 'Japan';");

Answer (score 0):

I came up with three possible solutions, none of them is actually guaranteed to work:

1. Does javascript's `document.readyState` return `"complete"`? If not, you could wait for that after every `click()`.
2. You could wait until `driver.switchTo().activeElement();` (which returns the active element) returns your text field, and begin your typing afterwards. I guess you should call `driver.switchTo().defaultContent();` afterwards, too, but am not sure about it. A similar approach would be getting `document.activeElement`.
3. Um, that's somewhat hacky, too. Write your own sendKeys method which finds the element, remembers it, and then sends one key from the wanted string at a time. Because WebDriver makes sure to have focus on the beginning of the typing, it should work.